# jQuery click and middle button behaviour

Tags: jquery, onclick, anchor

I have html code like this:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#foo">foo</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

When user clicks on the item will be invoked click handler.

What I want:

- Change hash in the handler method (using `window.location.hash`)
- When user clicks by left mouse click the handler should be called
- When user clicks by middle mouse (in Chrome, for example) link should be opened in new tab, but on the current page handler shouldn't be called
- Support another interactions with link: when user press enter on active link (he can activate it using `tab` key) or if he using browser extensions like vimperator or vimium

If I change hash in the handler middle button not opens new tab (but handler has been invoked on the current page), but it has been solved if don't invoke handler on events such as middle button click or click when ctrl or shift pressed

If I remove hash changing from the handler code, middle button opens new tab, but handler invoked on the current page.

Please give me some advice how to achieve my aims: should I implement `mousedown` handler along with click handler or may be there is more convenient method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a post about left-click vs other mouse buttons that should be helpful: http://www.jacklmoore.com/notes/click-events

It assumes you are using jQuery.  The particular button press is indicated in the event object under the `which` property.